# Override equals method

Tags: java, overriding, equals

newbie question here:

So in my university homework I have to override the object class equals method for a new class created by me.

The new class is "Product", each product has an "id" attribute which is unique. So this is how I Overrided it:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       final Product other = (Product) obj;
       if (id != other.id)
           return false;
       return true;
   }
```

The thing is that doing this is 1,5 points out of 10 and it made me suspicius to be that easy. So i started searching and I found things like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj)
           return true;
       if (obj == null)
           return false;
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
           return false;
       final Product other = (Product) obj;
       if (id != other.id)
           return false;
       return true;
   }
```

Which don't make sense for me at all, because I think that the last if check all the other ifs restrictions. What do you guys think?Which is the better way to Override this method?

Thanks!

Comment: The contract for equals says that all objects that are equal must have the same hash code.  So if you override equals() you must override hashCode().

Answer (score 14):

The second piece of code is better:

- It optimizes for `x.equals(x)`, which isn't necessary for correctness, but is a helpful optimization
- It copes with `x.equals(null)` instead of throwing `NullPointerException`
- It handles objects of a completely different class without throwing a `ClassCastException` which yours would (e.g. `x.equals("foo")`)
- It requires the *exact* same type to provide a symmetric relationship; otherwise `obj.equals(x)` could invoke a different method, giving a different result.

Comment: The second piece of code won't work if you subclass Product without changing the semantics of method equals().

Comment: @ignis: It depends on what you mean by "work". It won't treat an instance of Product as being equal to an instance of the subclass, no - but I don't think that's broken, it's just behaviour which needs to be documented.

Comment: a.equals(b) will always return false if a.getClass() == Product.class, b is instanceof some subclass of Product, and a and b have the same internal state. Thus the equals() relationship is not made symmetric. This violates java.lang.Object's contract.

Comment: @ignis: It will only be asymmetric if `b.equals(a)` returns true... and it wouldn't if it called `super.equals(a)` which it should. *Without* this check, `a.equals(b)` will only check for `id` so it could return true while `b.equals(a)` would return false as `a` isn't an instance of the same subclass of `Product` *or* a subclass of that subclass. The call to `getClass()` is precisely there to *aid* symmetry.

Comment: @ignis: How can a and b represent the same thing if they're different classes?  And why is your example not symmetric?  a.equals(b) would return false (because a.class == Product.class and b.class = SubProduct.class) and b.equals(a) would also return false (for the same reason).  If he were using instanceof, then you'd have asymmetric results for equals.

Comment: @nojo: If one has an abstract class which represents an immutable combination of values (e.g. a 2d matrix of `double`) but does not mandate a particular storage format, it may make sense to define the equality and hash code in terms of those values.  In such a case, an `IdentityMatrix with `Size` equal three might sensibly compare equal to a `DiagonalMatrix` with `DiagonalValues` holding {1.0,1.0,1.0}.

Answer (score 2):

The second version is a safe one, I would say a pedantic one. Your version, instead, could launch a `ClassCastException` because you are assuming that the runtime type of the variable `obj` is of type product. Which is not true, that's why you should use `this.getClass() != obj.getClass()` (you could solve this problem also with `instanceof` operator).

If I do

```
Product p = new Product();
p.equals("abc");
```

I get an exception while I should get `false`.

In addition it manages the `product.equals(null)` problem, which should return false as stated in `equals` contract method in documentation. If you don't care about this and you do, inside you equals:

```
...
Product p = (Product)obj; // obj is null
obj.id // this throws a NullPointerException
```

Comment: Using `instanceof` in a non-final class gives a symmetry problem if the class is subclassed.

Answer (score 1):

The common idiom used in overriding equals() is

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (! (obj instanceof Product) ) return false;

       final Product other = (Product) obj;
       if (id != other.id)
           return false;
       return true;
   }
```

In the second version that you posted:

- the first if() may be good for
  optimization only if the following
  checks are too much expensive. But
  this is not the case, so that is just
  redundant code which is evil.
- That version won't work if you define a Product subclass which
  does not change the semantics of method equals().
  (For example a class which
  provides some convenience method but
  no additional internal state to the
  objects.) This is because of the
  third if().

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 is right out of **Effective Java** for the safest way to override equals. 1 has a nullpointer if Object is null and it isn't as optimized as it could be(doesn't check if ojb is a reference to itself)

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by 'Joshua Bloch: Effective Java' is (assuming that `Product` does not have a superclass other than `Object`):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof Product)) return false;
    final Product other = (Product) obj;
    if (id != other.id) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Your first solution suffers from two drawbacks:

- `new Product(1).equals(null)` throws a NullpointerException although it is specified to return false in Object.equals().
- `new Product(1).equals(new Vector())` throws a ClassCastException although it is specified to return false in Object.equals().

Both of these are remedied by the instance check. The `if (this == obj) return true;` is often useful for efficiency, but probably not necessary here.

The second solution you posted makes it difficult to write a subclass of Product with good semantics. If you have a subclass

```
public class SubProduct extends Product {
    SubProduct(int id) {
         super(id);
    }
    ...
}
```

you will have `!new Product(4).equals(new SubProduct(4))`. This violates Liskov's susbstitution principle and is often believed to be not so good. If you have a final class
the second solutions is the same as the above.

Comment: Consider if `SubProduct` has some more state and further overrides `equals` - then if you use `instanceof` you end up with `a.equals(b) != b.equals(a)`, which violates the `Object` contract. Using the exact class may not always be what you want in terms of Liskov, but it *does* allow for subclassing without breaking the `Object` contract. Equality along an inheritance hierarchy is basically painful :(

Comment: Full agreement. I carefully avoided to say 'wrong'. I was not so careful reading the other answers, however, and missed your even more concise counter examples.