# Remove duplicates by certain key values

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap, hashset

Say I have my object

```
class MyObject{

    private int id;
    private int secondId;
    private String name;
    private String address;

}
```

And I'm adding lists of these objects to a list.

```
List<MyObject> finalList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
while(someCondition) {
      List<MyObject> l = getSomeMoreObjects();
      finalList.addAll(l);
}
```

This is all well and good, except I only want to add the new records to the list if they have a distinct `id` and `secondId`.

What would the best way to do this? I'm thinking it would involve using a `HashMap`.

Comment: Where there are duplicates in the two lists, is it important for `finalList` to retain the object it started with, or is it acceptable to *replace* that object with the dupe?

Comment: Do the `id` and `secondId` properties need to be *independently* unique, or is it the combination that needs to be unique?

Comment: Is it important to use a List, specifically?  Would it suffice to use a different type of order-preserving collection?  Is element order even important at all?

Comment: @JohnBollinger The combination needs to be unique. For example, if the existing list contains {1,1,"joe", "1234 St"}, {1,2, "Joe", "3333 St"} and {2,1, "James", "1234 St"} shold be added, while {1,1, "Jo", "1234 St"} should not.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, order preservation is not important.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in `MyObject`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 97 * hash + this.id;
    hash = 97 * hash + this.secondId;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof MyObject))
        return false;
    MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
    return this.id == other.id && this.secondId == other.secondId;
}
```

Then create the `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<MyObject> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Then just add objects to it:

```
set.add(new MyObject());
```

The `HashSet` will ignore your new object if you already have one with the same `id` and `secondId` in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Override the equals method in MyObject (two object are equal if and only if they have the same id and second id), and use a HashSet for storing distinct values.

Here is how you override the method:
[Override equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364258/override-equals-method)

Comment: You must also override `hashCode()` for this approach to work.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `HashSet`. For using `HashSet` -

1. override you `MyObject` `equals()` method and `hashCode()`.
2. add `l` to you `HashSet`